# Create a form from php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have posted it before, but i didn't get some clear answer. I am very confused about this:

i have the following html:

```
<body onload="showcontent()"> <!-- onload optional -->
        <div id="content"><img src="loading.gif"></div> <!-- leave img out if not onload -->
    </body>
```

I also have the following script:

```
function showcontent(){

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 1) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "<img src='loading.gif' />";
    }
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    } 
  }

  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'elsevier.php', true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

In elsevier.php I want when the rows of a table exceed 500 two buttons to be displayed, telling me whether to continue or cancel. If I put this code in the .php file nothing happens..... (except that two buttons appear).

```
if(mysqli_errno($con)==1062){
      @$q55="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testarticles";
      $result55 = mysqli_query($con, $q55);
      $row = $result55->fetch_row();
      echo '#: ', $row[0].'<br>';

      if($row[0]>=500&&$answer==false){
         echo '<form action="" method="GET">';
         echo "<label>Do you want to continue or cancel?</label>";
         echo '<input type="button" id="but1" name="but1" value="Continue">';
         echo '<input type="button" id="but2" name="but2" value="Cancel">';
         echo '</form>';

         if(isset($_GET["but1"])){
            $answer=true;
             break;
         }
          elseif(isset($_GET["but2"])){
             @$q56="DELETE * FROM journal, volume, issue, articles, testarticles WHERE import_time=$unixtimestamp";
             $result56 = mysqli_query($con, $q56);
             exit;
           }
      }
```

I want in this step the execution of the php script to stop and to display me the two buttons to choose from. If i press continue i want the script to execute from where it was stopped.

Has anybody any idea?? I have tried several things but nothing works... Thank you in advance!

Comment: I was wondering, why do your variable names containing SQL queries start with `@$q*`?

Comment: `@$q55`? When has assigning to a variable EVER failed?

Comment: some values are not declared, and for not displaying errors I put this in front..

Comment: Marc this is just wrong typing of me..

Comment: Also, just because you use mysqli, does not make your code SQL-injection-proof.

Comment: If you're inserting undeclared variables into your query strings, then you'll probably be generating invalid queries anyways.

Comment: sorry, it IS declared but it hasn't a value in a single parsing, for example...

Comment: So, are you actually getting error number 1062?  'Cause that would prevent all the PHP code from running...

Comment: i have other mysql queries as well.. the database part of my php file works perfectly.. the problem is the one i write... I think if i must put other html , javascript codes...

Answer (score 0):

Try with `input type="submit"` instead of `input type="button"`, submit will (obviously) submit the form, button are just button, when you click on it nothing will happen if you didn't link an action with js or whatever.